# How do I fix my MBR?

Tags: windows-7, mbr

I have a Windows 7 dvd but when I try all the methods of repair none of them work.  My main OS that is currently 'missing' is Windows 8 with Ubuntu dual boot.

Comment: Are you sure you want to fix the MBR (master boot record) and not the boot loader? If there is not MBR (or EUFI/GPT) then you can not boot at all. Reading your question I had the impression that you could load Ubuntu but not win8

Comment: So you cannot see windows 7 in the grub list?

Comment: I don't have the option to boot Ubuntu or Windows, so I need to fix the MBR.  How do I do this?

Comment: You really need to better describe the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

- Windows 7 (winPE) environment: After selecting repair cmd prompt type `BootRec.exe /fixmbr`

Edit1 after the comment: *When I typed that command in the CMD it said it was completed successfully but when I try to boot from my HD it still says "Missing Operating System"*

What happens if you replace `/fixmbr` with `/FixBoot`. This writes a boot sector onto the system partition to start Windows.

Alternatively try `/ScanOs` and `/RebuildBcd`.

NB: this also means your problem is **not** with the boot sector.

Comment: When I typed that command in the CMD it said it was completed successfully but when I try to boot from my HD it still says "Missing Operating System"

Comment: When I did /RebuildBcd it said it added windows.old but not windows.  Nothing was there when I tried to boot from HD.  I'm just going to put some files to a USB and then re-install Windows.