# Are there any pitfalls to moving my Windows partition to a new hard drive using dd?

Tags: windows, partitioning, migration, dd

My current hard drive has an 80 GB NTFS partition running Windows (`/dev/sda1`) in addition to several Linux partitions. I purchased a new hard drive and want to move my Windows 8 partition to a new NTFS partition (`/dev/sdb1`) where **`size(/dev/sdb1) >= size(/dev/sda1)`**. Are there any pitfalls to simply running this `dd` command from within my Linux distribution running on `/dev/sda2`?

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=32M
```

### Details

1. My Windows partition isn't currently mounted in Linux
2. I don't need to fix the MBR, because when I reinstall Linux on the new drive, GRUB2 will overwrite it anyway.
3. I know there are [other](https://superuser.com/a/375110/126046) [options](https://superuser.com/q/32164/126046) for performing this, like Clonezille, GParted, Acronis, Norton Ghost, Drive Image XML, ntfsclone, etc. but a single command seems the simplest and `dd` is  [highly](https://serverfault.com/a/4912/124808) [versatile](https://serverfault.com/a/5533/124808).

Comment: FWIW, I've used this approach successfully in the past.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I didn't run into any problems when I used this approach this time, so I'll probably use it in the future too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you have considered the problems I would have (size, MBR, etc) so I'd say you are fine to proceed. the only caution I give is they call DD 'Destroy Disk' for a reason. it is most unforgiving and quite capable of trashing your system beyond recognition. just make sure to triple check your disk file names (/dev/sdaX) and your syntax just to make sure.

Comment: Good advice. Frankly, if this Windows partition were to be trashed, it  would not be a problem since I use it about once a year, but copying the partition requires less effort than reinstalling the system.

Comment: Even if you do mess it up, if you can still boot from the old windows partition, do so (with the new/broken partition accessible to it), and use either the windows installer recovery console (http://superuser.com/questions/450689/how-do-i-fix-my-mbr) or EasyBCD (http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to try and fix issues with the GPT or windows' final-stage bootloader. Both take a lot less time and headache than a full reinstall.